# Proving the Validity of a Given Inequality Involving Ratios of $p$ and $q$

Tags: valid-inequalities, proofs

Consider the following inequality:

$$\left(\frac{p}{1-q}\right)^p \geq \left(\frac{q}{1-p}\right)^{1-p}$$

where $0<p, q< 1$ and $p+q<1$. I am trying to show that the following inequality holds true for all values of $p$ and $q$ that meet the conditions.

Comment: Unless context tying it to Operations Research is provided, this question seems more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the definition of KL divergence is enough?

If we eliminate the constraint that $q + p < 1$, notice that nothing changes in your inequality if I exchange $q$ and $1-q$.

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^p &\geq \left(\frac{1-q}{1-p}\right)^{(1-p)}\iff\\
\iff p\log\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) &\geq (1-p)\log\left(\frac{1-q}{1-p}\right)\\
\iff p\log\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) &\geq -(1-p)\log\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right)\\
\iff p\log\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) &+(1-p)\log\left(\frac{1-p}{1-q}\right) \geq 0\\
\iff D_{\text{KL}}(P\|Q) &\geq 0,
\end{align}

where $P,Q$ are the random variables over $\{0,1\}$ with probabilities $p,q$ of observing ones, respectively, and $D_{\text{KL}}(P\|Q)$ is the KL Divergence between $P$ and $Q$.

Since the KL divergence is always positive, the first line is always true, for any $p$, $q$ such that $0<\min\{p,q\}\leq\max\{p,q\},<1$

Comment: Yeah, this due to the property $\log(a) = -\log(1/a)$, for any positive $a$.

So, here I just took $a = \log(\frac{1-q}{1-p})$ and applied the property above